The behaviour of $(TargetPath) during .NET8 compilation for getting target exe
When I use $(TargetPath) in my PostBuildEvent for a .NET8 console project for the purpose of using signtool I find that it refers to the file .dll file and not the file .exe.
It makes sense to sign the .dll file as it is the actual program. But what MSBuild constant can I use to get the target exe?
At the moment I am doing it like this (lines split for clarity):
echo "$(SignToolPath)signtool.exe" sign 
    /d "$(TargetPath)" 
    /fd SHA256 
    /du "https://www.xyz.co.uk" 
    /f "d:\My Certificate.pfx" 
    /p "password" 
    /t "http://timestamp.sectigo.com" 
    /v "$(OutDir)" 

echo "$(SignToolPath)signtool.exe" sign 
    /d "$(OutDir)\$(TargetFramework)\$(AssemblyName).exe" 
    /fd SHA256 
    /du "https://www.xyz.co.uk" 
    /f "d:\My Certificate.pfx" 
    /p "password" 
    /t "http://timestamp.sectigo.com" 
    /v "$(OutDir)" 


Running the command requested in the comments, I can see (in this order):
<!-- Force .dll extension for .NETCoreApp and .NETStandard projects even if output type is exe. -->
<TargetExt Condition="'$(TargetExt)' == ''">.dll</TargetExt>


<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetExt Condition="'$(TargetExt)' == '' and '$(OutputType)'=='exe'">.exe</TargetExt>
    <TargetExt Condition="'$(TargetExt)' == '' and '$(OutputType)'=='winexe'">.exe</TargetExt>
    <TargetExt Condition="'$(TargetExt)' == '' and '$(OutputType)'=='appcontainerexe'">.exe</TargetExt>
    <TargetExt Condition="'$(TargetExt)' == '' and '$(OutputType)'=='library'">.dll</TargetExt>
    <TargetExt Condition="'$(TargetExt)' == '' and '$(OutputType)'=='module'">.netmodule</TargetExt>
    <TargetExt Condition="'$(TargetExt)' == '' and '$(OutputType)'=='winmdobj'">.winmdobj</TargetExt>
</PropertyGroup>


Was the project created as a console .exe project or was it manually converted to an .exe from a .dll project? What value does the $(TargetExt) property have? For a given project, the $(TargetPath) is the target produced by the project, e.g. it should be the .exe, but $(TargetPath) is generally set from the values of other properties.

@JonathanDodds I just followed the wizard and it created the EXE for me (which I want). I did nothing manual. But I tell a lie, this project was originally a .Net 4.6.2 Framework console exe and I used the dotnet tool to update it to a .net8. $(TargetExt) returns .dll.

Was the .Net Framework console project a legacy style project? And is the .Net 8 console project now an SDK style project? Does the SDK project define an $(OutputType) property with a value of Exe? (When I create a .Net 8 console project, $(OutputType) is set to be Exe.) It's possible you have stumbled onto a bug in the project conversion.

To get a better idea of what is actually happening, run msbuild -pp (or dotnet msbuild -pp) against your console project. The output will be the project will all Imports inlined. Search that output see where and how $(TargetExt) and $(TargetPath) are defined. See switches for detail about the preprocess switch.

@JonathanDodds See updated question. And it does have <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> present.

@JonathanDodds Not sure why the CSPROJ has <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"> in it. It used to be a 4.6,2.

Dotnet Core builds a cross-platform DLL containing your app's code and then create a stub executable for the targeted platform that will call the entry point in the DLL.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-framework-dependent
Since your app's code is compiled into a DLL, $(TargetPath) will refer to the DLL. To determine whether your app was compiled as a DLL and a stub executable, you can use the $(UseAppHost) property. It will be set to true if a stub executable was created, or be blank. To then access the path of the stub executable, you can use $(AssemblyName)$(_NativeExecutableExtension).
I got this information from searching through the output from dotnet build -pp.
To sign both the output DLLs and the stub executables, I'd use something like this:
  <Target Name="Code Signing" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SignTimestampUrl>http://timestamp.digicert.com</SignTimestampUrl>
      <SignCertName>Name of my cert</SignCertName>
      <SignToolPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe</SignToolPath>
      <SignCommand>"$(SignToolPath)" sign /a /n "$(SignCertName)" /t $(SignTimestampUrl)</SignCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Exec Command="$(SignCommand) &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot;" />
    <Exec Condition="$(UseAppHost) == 'true'" Command="$(SignCommand) &quot;$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName)$(_NativeExecutableExtension)&quot;" />
  </Target>



This solution worked for me:   remove PostBuildEvent in the csproj file then recreate the script in Visual Studio.
